# can i combine tcp TCP & UDP protocol

Tags: tcp, udp, protocols

I would like to create a new protocol, i.e having features of TCP and UDP. can you tell me what are tips and techniques are required if it is possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What particular features do you need? If you want a connectionless protocol, you'll need to add some checksum/sequence number to your packets, so you always know, if a packet was lost.

Comment: The question is far too broad to be answered here, but make sure you aren't reinventing [SCTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP gives you three features that UDP does not: (a) estimating sending rate, (b) retransmission, and (c) flow-control. In doing so, the tradefoff is that TCP becomes slower compared to UDP. So, if your application is delay sensitive, which is typically true for audio/video applications, then you need to start with UDP and keep whichever of the above three you want. Typically, UDP applications might add forward-error-correction or application layer packet-book-keeping to ensure retransmission.

There is yet another advantage that UDP offers which TCP does not: if you have an application that might use mulitcast. For such cases, UDP would be the right chioce since UDP can handle point to multipoint. Using TCP for multicast applications would be hard since now the sender would have to keep track of retransmissions/sending rate for multiple receivers.

So, in summary, UDP will offer you two features that TCP cannot: lower-delay and ability to do multicast. So, this way, we can actually reduce the scope of the question and ask what are the features of TCP that one would like to add to UDP since there is no way, one can add features of UDP to TCP.